# Joomla Start need assistance

Tags: css, joomla

I'm working on a Joomla project where basically I have to customize the login on the Sub-Header Menu. I know the file should be in html/ com_user / login. However from there I get stuck. So my questions are which file do I customize for the login panel to look the way I need it? 
Is it the default.php or default_login.php?

After I alter the CSS for this will it show up right away or do I need to additional changes?
Pretty much need assistance with and any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login view has been split into 2 view. 1 for login and 1 for logout. So the 2 files you see are sub views which get called by the default.php (main view) depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

So the file you need to edit is **default_login.php**.

You mentioned a login on the sub-menu so this makes me think it's the module rather than the component. In which case, you will need to make a template override for:

```
modules/mod_login
```

and then again, edit the **default_login.php**

Hope this helps

**Note:** Please ask your questions over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) which is the new dedicated Q&A site for Joomla  ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input and help with this. Much appreciated

Comment: @Philip - You're welcome. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted by click the tick icon